# Deploy Nestjs app to serverless and AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless

I have a Nestjs application and I want to deploy it to AWS Lambda using serverless.

In my app, `main.ts` (by default) -

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

At the root of my application, I have a `serverless.yml` -

```
service: serverless-backend
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: ap-south-1

functions:
  main:
    handler: src/lambda.ts
    events:
      - http:
        method: any
        path: /{any+}
```

I have a `src` inside which I have a `lambda.ts` file which needs to be configured to this serverless script to run.

How should I write `lambda.ts` in a typical Nest.js application?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Run nest build that generate ./dist folder on the root

```bash
nest build
```

Step 2: On the serveless.yml file create lambda function and include dist folder in the package

```yaml
functions:
  main:
    handler: dist/lambda.handler
    maximumEventAge: 300
    maximumRetryAttempts: 2
    timeout: 300
    memorySize: 4096
    package:
      include:
        - dist/**   <-- HERE
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /
          authorizer:
            name: authorizerFunc
            resultTtlInSeconds: 0
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
            allowCredentials: false
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: "{proxy+}"
          authorizer:
            name: authorizerFunc
            resultTtlInSeconds: 0
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
            allowCredentials: false
```

Step 3: Make sure to edit the right handler's name in the lambda.ts file, in my case it is "handler"

```js
    export const handler: Handler = async (
      event: any,
      context: Context,
      callback: Callback,
    ) => {
      server = server ?? (await bootstrap());
      return server(event, context, callback);
    };
```